# Offline Reinforcement Learning to Create Heuristics

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I am interested in using offline reinforcement learning to develop heuristics (aka dynamic treatment regimens) for when to send certain notifications to mobile app users.  I am unclear what the nuts and bolts are of the actual offline reinforcement learning.  If I were to use Q learning, would I get a model that is interpretable and I can develop rules based on the results?  Or is the only result a model which can then be applied to new data.

My question is similar to this, but I don't understand if/how you translate the results of the Q learning into a set of heuristics (e.g. don't send notifications if they received one in the last 2 hours, etc.): [Reinforcement Learning on Historical Data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298983/reinforcement-learning-on-historical-data)

I am new to RL, so maybe I am misunderstanding how complex it is and the optimizations are happening within individual, so no overarching set of rules can be crafted.  I do wonder if you could create subgroups and establish heuristics that optimize at the mean level?